# Integral of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, matrices

I have a function $f(x)$ which is expressed a linear combination of some basis functions $g_i(x)$:
$$
f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^N c_i g_i(x) = c^Tg(x)
$$
I would like to express $f(x)^2$ integrated over all $x$ in terms of the vector $c$ and some matrix involving the $g_i(x)$. Consider:
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)^2 dx &= \int \left( c^T g(x) \right)^2 dx \\
&= \int c^T g(x) g^T(x) c dx \\
&= c^T \left( \int g(x) g^T (x) dx\right) c \\
&= c^T G c
\end{align*}
where
$$
G_{ij} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g_i(x) g_j(x) dx
$$
My question is twofold:

**1) Am I allowed to move the $c^T$ and $c$ vectors outside the integral in the third step above?**

**2) In the third step, when I integrate the $N \times N$ matrix $g(x) g^T(x)$, is it correct to simply integrate each component of the matrix?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you can move the vectors outside the integral.  This is basically just the fact that integration is linear: $\int (a f(x) + b g(x))\; dx = a \int f(x)\; dx + b \int g(x)\; dx$, together with:
2. Yes, the integral of a vector or matrix is the vector or matrix of integrals of each component.